# Proving inf sup (lim x->y f(xn)) = sup(lim(f(x_n->y)))

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Can someone provide insight into proving this statement:

inf sup (lim x->y f(x_n)) = sup(lim(f(x_n-)))

Comment: What are $f$ and $x_n$? Please add clarification about what the statement fully is and consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your math.

Comment: Please clarify the question or it is likely to be closed.